Keep original header info for forwarded emails using Gmail filter
In Gmail, I set up a filter to forward specific emails to another email address (e.g., ext@email.domain). I want the forwarded emails to include the original header info at the top of the content of the email as any manually forwarded emails do.
However, the forwarded emails using the Gmail filter do not have the original header info included. It has a header as if it is the sender sending to ext@email.domain, like the redirect function of Outlook's rules, rather than including the original header info like ordinary forwarded emails, i.e., the forward function of Outlook's rules.
Is there any way to do this? A related discussion uses POP/IMAP but it retrieves all emails instead of my desired specific emails. If there is no quick fix, can scripting work this out?

There is no way to do this by using the built-in Gmail filter feature.
Yes, it's possible to do this by using "scripting". For this, you should use the Gmail API, Google Apps Script, a web scraping solution that reads the header from the original message, or scripting supported by another email client.
To use the Gmail API, you should create a project on Google Cloud, set the OAuth Consent Screen and set the credentials.
By using Google Apps Script, you might avoid doing the above manually; Google Apps Script will automatically create a Google Cloud project. You might use the GmailApp Service or the Gmail Advanced Service.
An example of a scraping solution might be to use user scripts. This could be done using bookmarklets, built-in web browser developer tools, and extensions like Tamper Monkey.
One example of scripting supported by another email client is to use VBA and Microsoft Outlook for Windows. Also, nowadays, it might be possible to use other programming languages, but it depends on the Outlook version, among other things.
Enjoy your journey into programming!
